# pulseaudio: Failed to initialize PA contextaudio: Could not init `pa' audio driver

Tags: linux, ubuntu, automotive-grade-linux

While trying to run AGL demo image using following command

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -m 2048 \
    -hda agl-demo-platform-qemux86-64.vmdk \
    -cpu kvm64 -cpu qemu64,+ssse3,+sse4.1,+sse4.2,+popcnt \
    -vga virtio -show-cursor \
    -device virtio-rng-pci \
    -serial mon:stdio -serial null \
    -soundhw hda \
    -net nic,vlan=0 \
    -net user,hostfwd=tcp::2222-:22
```

I am getting following error :

> qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000001H:ECX.svm [bit 2]
>   No protocol specified
>   xcb_connection_has_error() returned true
>   pulseaudio: pa_context_connect() failed
>   pulseaudio: Reason: Connection refused
>   pulseaudio: Failed to initialize PA contextaudio: Could not init `pa' audio driver
>   No protocol specified
>   xcb_connection_has_error() returned true
>   No protocol specified
>   Could not initialize SDL(No available video device) - exiting

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this?